# Spring Kafka Stream doesn't get written

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm writing a Spring Boot (2.1.4) app trying to use Spring Cloud Streams for Kafka.

What I'm trying to do is maintain a list of sensors on one topic ("sensors"). OTOH, I have incoming data on the other topic ("data"). What I'm trying to achieve is that when I get data for a sensor I don't already have, I want to add it to the sensor list.

To do that, I create a `KTable<String, Sensor>` from the sensors topic, map the temperature topic to the pure sensor's data (in this case, its name) and do an outer join with a `ValueJoiner` that retains the sensor if present, otherwise use the reading's sensor. Then, I write the result back to the sensors topic.

```
KTable<String, Sensor> sensorTable = ...;
KStream<String, SensorData> sensorDataStream = ...;

// get sensors providing measurements
KTable<String, Sensor> sensorsFromData =
        sensorDataStream.groupByKey()
                .aggregate(
                        Sensor::new,
                        (k, v, s) -> {
                            s.setName(k);
                            return s;
                        },
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), SensorSerde.SERDE));

// join both sensor tables, preferring the existing ones
KTable<String, Sensor> joinedSensorTable =
        sensorTable.outerJoin(
                sensorsFromData,
                // only use sensors from measurements if sensor not already present
                (ex, ft) -> (ex != null) ? ex : ft,
                Materialized.<String, Sensor, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(SENSORS_TABLE)
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(SensorSerde.SERDE));

// write to new topic for downstream services
joinedSensorTable.toStream();
```

This works fine if I create this using a `StreamBuilder` - i.e. if the `sensorTable` and `sensorDataStream` are coming from something like `builder.table("sensors", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), SensorSerde.SERDE))`.

However, I'm trying to use Spring Stream Binding for this, ie the above code is wrapped in

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(SensorTableBinding.class)
class StreamConfiguration {
    static final String SENSORS_TABLE = "sensors-table";

    @StreamListener
    @SendTo("sensorsOut")
    private KStream<String, Sensor> getDataFromData
            (@Input("sensors") KTable<String, Sensor> sensorTable,
                    @Input("data") KStream<String, SensorData> sensorDataStream) {
        // ...
        return joinedSensorTable.toStream();
    }
}
```

with a

```
interface SensorTableBinding {
    @Input("sensors")
    KTable<String, Sensor> sensorStream();

    @Output("sensorsOut")
    KStream<String, Sensor> sensorOutput();

    @Input("data")
    KStream<String, SensorData> sensorDataStream();
}
```

Here is the spring stream section of the application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers: ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.auto.offset.reset: latest

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.sensors.group: sensor-service
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.sensors.destination: sensors
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.sensorsOut.destination: sensors

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.data.group: sensor-service
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.data.destination: data
```

The stream gets initialized fine, and the join is performed (the key-value-store is filled properly), however, the resulting stream is never written to the "sensors" topic.

Why? Am I missing something?

Also: I'm sure there's a better way to de/serialize my objects from/to JSON using an existing Serde, rather than having to declare classes of my own to add to the processing (`SensorSerde`/`SensorDataSerde` are thin delegation wrapper to an `ObjectMapper`)?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you can put these in a small sample where it can be run standalone, we can take a look further. Looks like something configuration related.

Comment: @sobychacko Yes it was, I figured it out; check out the answer I gave if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data was written after all, but to the wrong topic, namely `sensorOut`.

The reason was the configuration. Instead of

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.sensors.destination: sensors
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.bindings.sensorsOut.destination: sensors
```

the topics are configured with this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sensors.destination: sensors
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sensorsOut.destination: sensors
```

For the sensors and data topic, that didn't matter, because the binding's name was the same as the topic; but since Spring couldn't find a proper destination for the output, it used the binding's name `sensorOut` and wrote the data there.

As a note, the whole configuration setup around these is very confusing. The individual items are documented, but it's hard to tell for each to which configuration prefix they belong. Looking into the source code doesn't help either, because at that level what's passed around are `Map`s with the key stripped of the prefix at runtime, so it's really hard to tell where the data is coming from and what it will contain.

IMO it would really help to have acual `@ConfigurationProperties`-like data classes passed around, which would make it so much easier to understand.